# How to update an object using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I am able to add data, but not sure how should I update the data. I am getting AddObject,DeleteObject methods not found any method to update.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply grab an (or multiple) object(s), manipulate them and call `SaveChanges` on the context. Of course, the object has to be attached to the context and tracking must enabled.

```
var obj = context.table.First(o => o.ID == 1);
obj.Property1 = data;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I tried this but not working

 Investor inv = context.Investors.First(i => i.InvestorId == new Guid(investorId));
                   if (inv != null)
                   {
                       inv.InvestorName = tbInvestorName.Value;
                       context.SaveChanges();
                   }

Comment: Hey Sorry My Mistake it was some diferent error..Thanks its working

Comment: Gives "The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship." error

Comment: Crystal Balling: The property you are changing has a key relationship with another model, but you aren't changing that model with the same value.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [Employee Info Starter Kit](http://eisk.codeplex.com/), you can consider the code snippet as below:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee updatedEmployee)
        {
            //attaching and making ready for parsistance
            if (updatedEmployee.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
                _DatabaseContext.Employees.Attach(updatedEmployee);
            _DatabaseContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(updatedEmployee, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            _DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```